# REGEX Trocar pontuação da alternativa

Tags: javascript, regex

Fiz essa regex = `/^[A-Z][.]|[A-Z] [.]/gmi`

Ela seleciona todas as letras das alternativas eu gostaria de saber como uso isso para onde é A. substituir por A) onde é b. substituir por b)
Tipo um replace que respeita as letras do regex e as troca por ela mesmo + parênteses.

```
function pontoParentese(texto) {
    const expressao = /^[A-Z][.]|[A-Z] [.]/gmi
    console.log(expressao)
    texto = texto.replaceAll(expressao, 'A)')
    return window.document.getElementById("cxTexto").value = texto
}
```

Meu problema está no segundo argumento do replace, assim ele vai substituir tudo por A) independente da letra, e não é oque eu quero.

Podemos definir a Idade Moderna como:

A. mesmo que com limitações, é o período de transição entre o feudalismo e o capitalismo.

b . momento que o ser humano pisou na lua.

C. período de transição entre a Roma Antiga e o Renascimento.

D. – momento que alterou a vida humana por causa de duas grandes
guerras mundiais.

e . – período de transição da Revolução Francesa à Segunda Guerra Mundia.

Comment: Pronto arrumado. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Estou indo almoçar, o código solução está nesse [link](https://ideone.com/iAiccE) quando eu voltar do almoço escrevo uma resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use essa expressão:

```
/^([A-Z])\s?\./gmi
```

As *flags* `gmi` você já deve saber, na ordem: *global*, *multiline* e *case insentitive*.

Explicando a expressão:

```
^        Início da linha
([A-Z])  Captura no grupo 1, que será usando no replace,
         uma letra entre A e Z
\s?      Espaço opcional. O sinal de "?" torna opcional o espaço
         representado pelo \s
\.       Ponto escapado, que é o próprio caractere "."
```

**Resumo:** no início de cada linha deve ter uma letra de A a Z seguida de um ponto, e entre essa letra e o ponto pode ou não ter um espaço. Se isso acontecer, a letra será guardada no grupo $1.

No `replace` você usa o grupo `$1` para substituir a letra e inclui o parênteses:

```
texto = texto.replaceAll(expressao, '$1)');
```

Exemplo:

```js
function pontoParentese(texto) {
    const expressao = /^([A-Z])\s?\./gmi
    texto = texto.replaceAll(expressao, '$1)');
    return window.document.getElementById("cxTexto").value = texto;
}

pontoParentese(document.getElementById("cxTexto").value);
```

```css
#cxTexto{
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
 }
```

```html
<textarea id="cxTexto">
Podemos definir a Idade Moderna como:

A. mesmo que com limitações, é o período de transição entre o feudalismo e o capitalismo.

b . momento que o ser humano pisou na lua.

C. período de transição entre a Roma Antiga e o Renascimento.

D. – momento que alterou a vida humana por causa de duas grandes guerras mundiais.

e . – período de transição da Revolução Francesa à Segunda Guerra Mundia.
</textarea>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou demais.

Comment: Quem votou negativo poderia por favor explicar qual o motivo do voto? Pois realmente não consigo encontrar nenhum equivoco na resposta. Se há algo que viu, exponha pois iria ajudar a todos.